# How to apply css to perticular word inside a textarea

Tags: html, css

I want to apply a style to a particular word in `textarea`. Here is my textarea text:

```
<textarea id="shareMessage" name="shareMessage" required> I found something you’ll really want </textarea>
```

I want to make the word 'something' italic. I have tried using the italic tag inside the textarea, but the problem is that I can't use any tag inside of textarea.

Comment: Pretty sure you can’t

Comment: I'm just thinking out loud here, but you could possibly search for the word via javascript / jQuery and then add a <b>perticular word</b> to the textarea.

Comment: @TimothyKruger The `textarea` element does not support any *inline* styling.

Comment: @str aaaah Ok cool, wasn't too sure if it did.  Thanks for making me aware of that fact.

Answer (score 5):

Not possible using textarea... Try using the [`contenteditable` attribute](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/HTML/Editable_content) on a `div` something like this...

```html
<div contenteditable id="shareMessage"> I found <em>something</em> you'll really want </div>
```

Also if you want to take a rich text input from the user you should try something like [Medium.js](http://jakiestfu.github.io/Medium.js/docs/), [TinyMCE](https://www.tiny.cloud/), etc to gain more control...

Comment: I also tried using div.it works but i am finding the if you cn do this with textarea.

Comment: @SmitaKagwade you can't achieve what you want using `textarea`... Also I hope you noticed the `div` is actually editable so behaves like a `textarea`...